# Passing data to a taghelper

Tags: c#, viewbag, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I'm using a TagHelper to localise any text on a number of CSHTML pages.  In order to select the correct translation the TagHelper needs to know the locale that the user currently has selected, which is held in the user's LocalStorage.

I have been able to populate a `ViewBag` with this value, so I can add it somewhere on the page using Razor syntax  but I can't figure out how to make this information available every time a TagHelper processes a specified `HtmlTargetElement`.  I've a feeling that the answer is somewhere in `TagHelperContext` and have tried adding the locale to the page's `<body>` tag but the order that the HtmlTargetElements are processed do not seem to be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> which is held in the user's LocalStorage

Local storage is not accessible server-side (where the tag helper is being rendered). Therefore, there is no way to achieve this. You could perhaps use the session, instead, which you could then access in your tag helper via `ViewContext`. In your tag helper add the following property:

```
[HtmlAttributeNotBound]
[ViewContext]
public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }
```

Then, you can access the session via `ViewContext.HttpContext.Session`.

Comment: You seem to have missed the bit where I say that I already have the value available to the server-side and used it to populate a ViewBag.  I will investigate the ViewContext though.

Comment: Luckily the locale value was already being passed as part of the request so I was indeed able to use ViewContext to retrieve it.